# Using jQuery .fadeOut() on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML-

```
<input id="skipOnClick" type="checkbox">-   Skip song when notification is clicked?</input>
```

Then when I run this jQuery `$('#skipOnClick').fadeOut();`, only the checkbox fades and not the text with it. Is there a way that both the checkbox and text can fade or am I going to have to use another HTML element to put the text in and fade both the checkbox and element?

Comment: FYI, there are labels to put that text and relate it to the field using a `for` attribute. Wrap the `input`  and `label` in a `p` or `div` or whatever element you wish to.. and then fade that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input element cannot have a text within it, so you need to wrap the text and input in another element like a label then hide it like

```
<label for="skipOnClick" id="lblSkipOnClick">
    <input id="skipOnClick" type="checkbox">-   Skip song when notification is clicked?
</label>
```

then

```
$('#lblSkipOnClick').fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

I experimented a bit before I posted the question and found that by placing all the HTML inside of a `div` tag then using `$('#skipHolder').fadeOut();` fixed the problem.

The HTML-

```
<div id="skipHolder">
<input id="skipOnClick" type="checkbox">-   Skip song when notification is clicked?</input>
</div>
```

Comment: i recommend to use Arun's repy because at your solution, to change the checkbox's state, you have to click on the checkbox itself. By using `<label>`, you can make the text content clickable to change the checkbox's state. That's more user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

just put your checkbox inside li

**HTML**

```
 <input id="skipOnClick" type="checkbox"/><span>- Skip song when notification is clicked?</span>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#skipOnClick').change(function(){

$('#skipOnClick').fadeOut();
    $('#skipOnClick').next('span').fadeOut();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CYLcY/41/)**

Comment: it's not an accurate answer. You have to add a list for single item. Or if you have multiple checkboxes, the above code will remove all list items from display. Also, the asker asked to use `.fadeOut()`, not `.hide()`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a text content inside the checkpox `<input>`tag. Rather, put a label for it and then fade both of them:

HTML

```
<input id="skipOnClick" type="checkbox"></input>
<label for="skipOnClick">-   Skip song when notification is clicked?</label>
```

Javascript

```
$('#skipOnClick').fadeOut();
$('#skipOnClick').next("label").fadeOut();
```